# After changing the table Entity Name in EF edmx designer then Not able to Create controller with Scaffolding options?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I have tblDepartment and tblEmployee in Database. Added entity data model for data and changing Entities "tblDepartment" to "Department" and 
"tblEmployee" to "Employee" .
While  Creating Employeecontroller with read/write/edit template using entityframework and scaffolding template then Model Entity "Employee" 
not found in dropdown instead it shows "tblEmployee" in dropdown.
Please help.
Thanks,
Dnyaneshwar

Answer (score 1):

**Build / Rebuild** the solution or your project. Your updates will not automatically reflect esp on controllers.